# How to encapsulate data in javascript without function duplication in every object instance?

Tags: javascript, oop, duplicates, encapsulation

I create a class in JavaScript with public and private properties - data and methods to operate on this data. Some data is private and should not be accessible via "."(dot) operator from class instance. Is there way to avoid method duplication for every class instance?

```
function MyClass() {
    let privateVar;
    let publicVar;
    function publicFun() {
        // do something
    }
    function privateFun(){
        // do something else
    }
    this.v = publicVar;
    this.f = publicFun;
}

let obj1 = new MyClass();
let obj2 = new MyClass();   // publicFun and privateFun methods duplication
```

`ClassName.prototype` approach require completely public API for all class data. So this doesn't work for me.

Comment: So if I understand right, you wish to have conditional approach for available functions in different instances of same function. Am I right?

Comment: I have been dabbling with these things for quite a while and I have managed to make it work perfectly fit to an OOP model (without the use of ES6 though, that completely reworks how we would write it), but i do not understand what your question/issue is?

Comment: can you show example of your class? and show what exactly you want to hide.

Comment: Same functions. Just like in C++ classes for example. When we create class instance there are on additional memory allocation for functions, only for data. here we create separate instance for every method described in the class. So I would like to care about memory usage only.

Comment: I still do not understand your question properly, but if you wish to remove duplication of function, using `prototype` should do it. Right?

Comment: `prototype` pattern force me to open access to all data to operate with them. But I would like to encapsulate data in class description

Comment: Let me try to grasp what you are aiming at, if you create a class in JS and have it's instance created 100 times, you are worried that you will have a method (function) also defined 100 times, and thus wasting memory? You'd want methods defined on the class, not on the instance of the object? The only way I see this doable without exposing the class data would be either by making a wrapper function, defining functions within, then returning the 'class function' from it (via closure) or by making a 'class registry' of sorts, which would have 'createNewInstance', same principle.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my example if I understood you correctly:

1. Methods are defined only once, within the wrapper function (thus they are not declared on every instance)
2. You can create instances of objects they will all refer to the same methods, and can have exposed data.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/njLkc8xh/3/) is a fiddle example:

```
function wrapper() {
  //Methods defined only once
  function method() {
    alert("this is method");
  }

  function methodWithParams(param, callback) {
    var paramsVar = param;

    function realMethodHere() {
      alert("We passed a param: " + paramsVar);
      paramsVar = "Changed"
      callback(paramsVar);
      alert("Now we cahnged the param's value to: " + paramsVar + ", rerun the method to verify");
    }

    return realMethodHere;
  }

  //Class constructor
  function classConstructor() {
    //Private
    var privateData = "Private"

    function privateFunction() {
      alert("this is some private function, inaccesible");
    }

    //This callback was addedto allow yo uto change private data.
    function privateDataChangerCallback(param) {
      privateData = param;
    }


    //Public
    this.publicData = "Public"
    this.callMethod = method;
    this.paramMethod = methodWithParams(privateData, privateDataChangerCallback);
  }


  return classConstructor;
}

var classDefinition = wrapper();
var classInstance = new classDefinition();

classInstance.callMethod(); //method without param
classInstance.paramMethod(); //method with exposed Private data
//rerunning the method to see what the value is:
classInstance.paramMethod(); //method with exposed Private data
```

Comment: If I understood this example correctly, here we have the same problem: every method you declared in `wrapper` here duplicates for every `new(wrapper())();` call. Is't it?

Comment: You are right, my mistake, updated the example and the code to reflect it NOT to happen. Like this it should work. This way wrapper is called only once, the class definition is called multiple times, so every instance is made again, but methods are only made once.

Comment: Hmmm... But  what would we see if `privateData` variable we pass to the `methodWithParams` is not an Object type (number, string, bool)? `methodWithParams` will receive a copy of `privateData` but not a reference.

Comment: I am not sure what are you aiming at. At the time of the constructor, the method `methodWithParams` is being run, parameters you defined are being passed to it, this is run only once the constructor is called. The result of the method is a function call as defined by `realMethodHere` which keeps whatever parameter you passed onto the `methodWithParams` at the time of object initialization. If you pass a reference such as an Object or an Array, the `realMethodHere` has a reference, if you pass a value, such as a number, bool or string, the `realMethodHere` gets the value.

Comment: Sure, but if we would try to change the non-Object type variable passed to the `methodWithParams` it would change only local copy (inside a `methodWithParams` function scope) but not the variable of class object. So when the variable copied by `methodWithParams()` call, it is not anymore reference to variable of the class instance. They just independent!

Comment: You mean to say, that you want a method to change a private value, within the instance of the object, where this value is not a reference passed value, such as calling a method, that changes the value of a private variable from `"foo"` to `"bar"` or from `1` to `2`?   I do not think this is possible. What you are asking is to define a function (method) outside of the scope of another function (constructor) that would have access to the variables (private) that are contained within it's child's closure.

Explaining below:

Comment: You have a wrapper function with it's private properties and functions, contained within, these are only accessible to the inside of the function's body (scope). This function within itself defines another function, which is a constructor, which then has it's own private properties. These properties are not, in any way accessible by the outer scope. You are requesting to access the properties of an inner scope through an outer scope essentially, without exposing these properties by a publicly accessible methods of the inner function. Not possible.

Comment: The only thing that you COULD do is use callbacks, if you want an example with these, I am willing to change the model, though, callbacks will be redefined and re-declared for every instance of the object, so I am not sure if we are really saving any memory that way. Sure you save memory for references to the things that are passable as reference. Alternatively, wrap all of your properties within objects, that way everything is passable by reference.

Comment: Yes. Definitively your approach is a kind of solution for my question. But I don't sure of does it worth to use it in practice. :(
Probably I should not care about the memory for this time.

Comment: I've edited the fiddle and the related code in the answer to reflect how the callback would function. Mind you this callback is re-declared for every instance, there is no way around it. Passing the callback to the method, you are exposing a way for the method to reference your specific object. Alternative solution, as said would be to wrap all your properties in objects, this allows you to pass them by reference and in this case you DO NOT need callbacks, so no matter how many instances you make you do not bloat memory.

Comment: Weather this entire thing is justified form a memory conservation point of view, I don't know I am not an expert on memory, but I would assume it is not justified. This requires a lot of "wrapping" of the code to make it work in a conservative matter, I wouldn't bother with it to THAT extent. If given a choice of which one to use, I'd rather wrap my properties in objects, or even make all the properties a single object, which is passed, in it's entirety to any method, and then use object's properties to behave as my properties. This would avoid callbacks being declared per instance.

Comment: @John_Domestos I discovered one additional thing, am working on it, will provide link when done, it behaves strange

Comment: Okay so, false alarm basically.... regardless I ended up making the 'object wrapped' properties as suggested in the process of discovering what was going on, you might as well have this one. I'd prefer this method over the method of callbacks, in all honesty + it keeps the memory usage lower, cheers!

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzhutpph/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) it's a javascript library that support OOP so you can write your code like in c# or java and the compiler will generate the real javascript for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stand-alone function in the `constructor` function:

```js
var HelloWorld = (function () {
 function anonymouse() {
  return "MUHAHAHA! ALL MINE!!!";
 }
    function HelloWorld() {
        this.greeting = "Hello World";
    }
    //public
    HelloWorld.prototype.greet = function () {
        console.log("Hello, " + this.greeting + " " + anonymouse());
    };
    return HelloWorld;
}());
var greeter = new HelloWorld();
greeter.greet();

console.log(greeter);
```

But this does have the side effect of duplicating said function on all instances of your class.

Alternatively, maybe create a namespace to hide it in, and reference your functions from there. That would eliminate the duplicate function issue:

```js
var MySecretClasses;
(function (MySecretClasses) {
    function anonymouse() {
        return "MUHAHAHA! ALL MINE!!!";
    }
    var HelloWorld = (function () {
        function HelloWorld() {
            this.greeting = "Hello World";
        }
        //public
        HelloWorld.prototype.greet = function () {
            console.log("Hello, " + this.greeting + " " + anonymouse());
        };
        return HelloWorld;
    }());
    MySecretClasses.HelloWorld = HelloWorld;
})(MySecretClasses || (MySecretClasses = {}));
var greeter = new MySecretClasses.HelloWorld();
greeter.greet();
console.log(MySecretClasses);
console.log(greeter);
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

As [Shlomi Haver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5505232/shlomi-haver) points out, you could use [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) for this.

```
module MySecretClasses {

    function anonymouse() {
            return "MUHAHAHA! ALL MINE!!!";
    } 
    export class HelloWorld {
        greeting: string = "Hello World";
        constructor() {

        }
        //public
        public greet() {
            console.log("Hello, " + this.greeting + anonymouse());
        }
    }
}
var  greeter = new MySecretClasses.HelloWorld();
greeter.greet();
console.log(greeter);
```

Comment: For me it is very complex code! Very hard to maintain!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you can add a parameter to your class definition and based on this parameter, you can choose to include additional properties to your return object.

#### Sample

```js
function myClass(option) {
  var myFunc1 = function() {}
  var myFunc2 = function() {}
  var myFunc3 = function() {}
  var myFunc4 = function() {}
  var myFunc5 = function() {}

  var finalProps = {
    myFunc1: myFunc1,
    myFunc2: myFunc2,
  }

  switch (option) {
    case "all":
      finalProps["myFunc5"] = myFunc5;
    case "more":
      finalProps["myFunc3"] = myFunc3;
      finalProps["myFunc4"] = myFunc4;
      break;
  }
  return finalProps;
}

(function() {
  var f1 = new myClass();
  var f2 = new myClass("more");
  var f3 = new myClass("all");

  console.log(f1, f2, f3)
})()
```